# Having had or having?

Tags: grammar, tense

> I saw him roaming around the city after I saw his twin brother
> tumbling down the stairs after having a chat with his twin brother.

> I saw him roaming around the city after I saw his twin brother
> tumbling down the stairs after having had a chat with his twin
> brother.

Are both ok, or is the second the correct one?

Order of events:

1. now
2. I saw him
3. tumbling down
4. had a chat

Answer (score 2):

This probably doesn't answer the point of your question, but you should rethink your sentence. Complex constructs are often awkward and difficult to understand, so try to make it simple instead. You also need to clarify who the subjects are. It's not clear if **he** had a chat with his twin brother, or **you** did.

Your order of events shows he or you had a chat last, but that doesn't make sense to me given what you've written. It seems that the order would be:

(1) First he (or you) had a chat with his twin brother.

(2) Then you saw his twin brother tumbling down the stairs.

(3) Then you saw him roaming around the city.

> After [I | he] had a chat with his twin brother, I saw his twin brother tumbling down the stairs and I saw him roaming around the city.

If *you* had the chat with his twin brother, you can also say:

> After having a chat with his twin brother, I saw his twin brother tumbling down the stairs and I saw him roaming around the city.

Answer (score 1):

> I saw him roaming around the city after I saw his twin brother tumbling down the stairs after having a chat with his twin brother.

The second appearance of *after*, heading the preposition phrase, makes the sentence clumsy. The use of *having had* does not help.

I would break the sentence into two.  As swmcdonnell said, it is unclear who had a chat with the *twin brother*.

> I saw him roaming around the city after I saw his twin brother tumbling down the stairs.  That was after **he (or I) had** a chat with his twin brother.